# Adding service initialization method when using Castle Windsor IoC container

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

If my service have some initialization code, I know two options:

1. Implement [ISupportInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx).
   Pro: Only depend on .NET native interface.
   Con: I normally only use BeginInit(), so there's always unneccessary code of empty EndInit()
2. Implement Castle Core's IInitializable.
   Pro: Only one method needs to be implemented.
   Con: I have to make my class depend on Castle Core.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: You can create your own interface and use that. What you are doing here is called temporal coupling and considered a design smell by many. Read [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) for more information.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth If I create my own interface, how does Castle Windsor know that it should execute those codes?

Comment: It doesn't. I didn't know the code was to be executed automatically.

Comment: but it seems to automatically execute the code if I implement ISupportInitialize or IInitializable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
Component.For<Foo>().OnCreate(foo => foo.WhateverMethodYouWant());
```

The details are [in the documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#OnCreate_7).

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the `OnCreate` for every component that implements a certain interface?

Comment: .ConfigureFor<IFoo>(c=>c.OnCreate(something))

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to convert the components  concerned into Castle Facilities where you have much more explicit control but this is probably overkill.

I would just go with option 1. The redundant EndInit is inconsequential.